# SwiftUI : animate row expand in List

Tags: list, animation, swiftui

I need to expand each row of a `List` with a smooth animation (from top to bottom). A row has a main text (always displayed) and a secondary text that is shown only when row is expanded.

Here is code for `List`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach((1...3), id: \.self) { _ in
                    ItemRow()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Demo")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

And for `ItemRow`:

```swift
struct ItemRow: View {
    
    @State private var expanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Hello world")
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "chevron.forward.circle")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(expanded ? 90 : 0))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation() {
                            expanded.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
            
            if expanded {
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Vel dicta error qui vero incidunt et fugit quisquam aut modi praesentium qui veritatis sed ipsam magnam. Ad iure velit ut possimus voluptatem cum dolores dicta. Ex cupiditate libero ut impedit internos aut reprehenderit molestias! Aut debitis dignissimos sit incidunt internos aut mollitia explicabo aut vitae numquam et repellendus iusto.")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .frame(height: expanded ? nil : 0)
                    .clipped()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rows expand when I tap on chevron button. But the animation is not smooth at all: the main text starts in center at first and moves on top of row. [Demo video](https://apps.gander.family/demo.mp4)
The goal is that main text stays on top (fixed) and the secondary text (and all row height) expands from top to bottom.

If I replace `List` in `ContentView` with `ScrollView` the animation is a bit better. But the UI does not look like a standard `List` anymore. And I need `List` features (like `swipeActions`).

Any idea how to make a great animation by keeping `List`?

Comment: Have you tried DisclosureGroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is [DisclosureGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup) from Apple.

Just replace your ItemRow with the following:

```
struct ItemRow: View {

    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup {
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Vel dicta error qui vero incidunt et fugit quisquam aut modi praesentium qui veritatis sed ipsam magnam. Ad iure velit ut possimus voluptatem cum dolores dicta. Ex cupiditate libero ut impedit internos aut reprehenderit molestias! Aut debitis dignissimos sit incidunt internos aut mollitia explicabo aut vitae numquam et repellendus iusto.")
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .font(.caption)
                .clipped()
        } label: {
            Text("Hello world")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the animation you get:

[image]

---

**Since DiscloureButtonStyle is iOS 16 Beta only, here is a trick to show custom chevron (I don't recommend this approach btw):**

```
struct ItemRow: View {
    @State private var expanded = false

    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $expanded) {
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Vel dicta error qui vero incidunt et fugit quisquam aut modi praesentium qui veritatis sed ipsam magnam. Ad iure velit ut possimus voluptatem cum dolores dicta. Ex cupiditate libero ut impedit internos aut reprehenderit molestias! Aut debitis dignissimos sit incidunt internos aut mollitia explicabo aut vitae numquam et repellendus iusto.")
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .font(.caption)
                .clipped()
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Hello world")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.forward.circle")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(expanded ? 90 : 0))
            }.padding(.trailing, -20) // <-- To use the space of the default one
        }.accentColor(.clear) // <-- To hide the default one

    }
}
```

Comment: It works very well! Thank you.
I've used it in my main project where I have more complexe rows and it works.

Comment: Is there a way to change chevron by another image? Or customize anythink of this DisclosureGroup?

Comment: There is `DisclosureGroupStyle` like `ButtonStyle`. You can create a custom one. But unfortunately, it is iOS 16 only. (I will update the answer with a trick that I don't recommend)

Comment: OK I get it. Yes, it's not a good idea but I do the job. Thanks again.